# How to create a member that filters data across dimensions?

Tags: mdx

I would like to create a calculated member, (or whatever is best) that will filter data based on a set of conditions.
Example:  If [dimension1].[attribute1] = 'Y', and if [dimension2].[attribute2] between 0 and 8, then "call this member "Red", else, call this member "black".

I would like to then be able to drag whichever member i need to the where clause of a MDX statement, and have it filter the data based on the conditions i specified.
     I am new to this, and if someone can give me a sample query to do this, i would sure appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
MEMBER A AS
STRTOVAL( [dimension2].[attribute2].currentmember.name)

MEMBER B AS
IIF(A >=0 AND A < 9 AND [dimension1].[attribute1].currentmember IS [dimension1].[attribute1].&[y],'Red', 'Black'
```

I created two members.  The first handles the range.  Attributes are stored as text, they need to be converted.  This was it's own member due to needing to reference it twice in member B.  Member B is a basic IIF that includes the conditions and outputs specified.

For these members to work, Dimension1.attribute1 and dimension2.Attribute2 will need to be present in your select statement.